# How to different test and production version?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications, vaadin

I have created a webapp with vaadin in java ee. The properties are swapped out and are read in at program start. Now I want to have two different properties. Once for the test system and one for the production system. How can I now distinguish in the code which property file I call? Maybe by the name of the war-file?

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (os.contains("windows")) {
            path = "C:/ProgramData/mySampleWebapp/";
        } else if (os.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || os.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || os.indexOf("aix") >= 0) {
            path = "/etc/mySampleWebapp/";
        }
```

My current code is currently differentiating between Windows and Linux now I want to extend that with test and productive.

Comment: Add a property in your web.xml which tells you if it's test/production/development

Comment: You can add properties via command line and then use System.getenv() or System.getProperty(). Imho code should be environment agnostic. If you really need it use I wouldn't ship any hardcoded environment-related variables.

Comment: @JoseJuanCalderonViedma has a good point regarding the code being env agnostic. Depending on how/where you want to test, you usually have some sort of a profile system. For example [Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) will allow you to define files for each of the dev, test, pro profiles. Or via [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) you can have packaging profiles that would include the specific property files for the build which you are targeting.